# Javascript: when creating an object, how do you set something like myObject.name?

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
location = {place1: distance1, place2:distance2};
```

How do I set something like location.name = location, so that I can access the "location" string later on?

Would something like this work?

```
location = {
    place1: distance1,
    place2: distance2
    location.name = "location";
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i dont get what youre trying to do. just set the name?

Comment: Do you want to dynamically set the property name?

Comment: `window.location` has meaning! You need to pick a different variable name if it is a global variable

Comment: Are you trying to store a reference to the variable `location` inside the object?

Answer (score 6):

```
location = {
    place1: distance1,
    place2: distance2,
    name : "location"
}
```

Comment: I suspect there's more to the question than this, but enjoy the easy rep in the meantime! :)

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything is possible in js :)

```
my_location = {
    place1: distance1,
    place2: distance2
};
my_location.name = "location";

alert(my_location.place1 + ' ' + my_location.place2 + ' ' + my_location.name);
```

Another way:

```
function MyLocation(distance1, distance2){
    this.place1 = distance1;
    this.place2 = distance2;
}
my_location = new MyLocation(dist1, dist2);
my_location.name = "location";
alert(my_location.place1 + ' ' + my_location.place2 + ' ' + my_location.name);
```